# can not filter data from the database using the search form in php oop using PDO

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to make a search form that will search the database table and display on the table. There are 3 sections. 
1. index.php 
2. process_studennt.php
3. Database.php

from the form  it will go to the process_studennt.php then it go to the Database.php and after that it will come back and give the result in the table.

But I am having problem with it. Please help.

The warning is :

> Notice: Undefined index: valuetosearch in
>   H:\install\xampp\htdocs\crud\index.php on line 46
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   H:\install\xampp\htdocs\crud\lib\Database.php on line 274
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_student' at line 1 in
>   H:\install\xampp\htdocs\crud\lib\Database.php:280 Stack trace: #0
>   H:\install\xampp\htdocs\crud\lib\Database.php(280):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 H:\install\xampp\htdocs\crud\index.php(88):
>   Database->search('tbl_student', Array) #2 {main} thrown in

My form in the index.php page is :

> ```
>               <form class="form form-control" action="lib/process_student.php" method="POST" >
>                   <fieldset class="form-group">
>                             <input type="text" class="form-control-sm"  name="valuetosearch" placeholder="Search..">
>                             <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
>                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="search" Value="Search">
>                     </fieldset>
> ```

and the table to show the result is:

```
> /*
>                           search section 
> 
>                            */
> 
> 
>                           $searchdata = $db-> search($tablename,$selectcon);
>                           if (!empty($searchdata)) {
>                               ?>
>                               <tr>
>                                       <td><?php echo $searchdata["id"];; ?></td>
>                                       <td><?php echo $searchdata["name"]; ?></td>
>                                       <td><?php echo $searchdata["email"]; ?></td>
>                                       <td><?php echo $searchdata["phone"]; ?></td>
>                                       <td>
>                                           <a href="editstudent.php?id=<?php echo $searchdata["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
>                                           <a href="lib/process_student.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $searchdata["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
>                                       </td>
>                                   </tr>
>                               <?php
>                           } else {
>                               # code...
>                           }
>                           
> 
>                            ?>
```

the process_student.php file section:

```
// search section

    elseif ($_REQUEST["action"] == "search" && !empty($_REQUEST["action"])) {
        $searchvalue = $_POST["valuetosearch"];
        if (!empty($searchvalue)) {

            $tablename = "tbl_student";
            $condition = ["name" => $searchvalue];
            $searchdata = $db->search($tablename,$condition);

            if ($searchdata) {
                $msg = "Data founded";

            } else {
                $msg = "Error! No data founded";

            }

            /*
            redirecting to the index page 

             */
            Session::set("msg",$msg);
            $home_url = "../index.php"; 

            header("Location: ".$home_url);
        } else {
            # code...
        }
```

And the Database.php section :

```
public function search($tablename,$data)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT ";
        $sql .= array_key_exists("select", $data)?$data["select"]:"*";
        $sql .= " FROM ".$tablename;
        if (array_key_exists("where", $data)) {
            $sql .= " WHERE ";
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($data["where"] as $key => $value) {
                $add = ($i > 0)?" OR " : "";
                $sql .= "$add"."$key=:$key";
                $i++;
            }
        }





        // now prepare and execute
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        // bind value
        if (array_key_exists("select", $data)) {
            foreach ($data["select"] as $key => $value) {
                $query->bindValue(":$key","$value");
            }
        }

        // now execute
        $query->execute();

        // now for the return type

        if (array_key_exists("return_type", $data)) {
            switch ($data["return_type"]) {
                case 'count':
                    $value = $query->rowCount();
                    break;
                case 'single':
                    $value = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    break;  

                default:
                    $value = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
        elseif ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
            $value = $query->fetchAll();
        }

        // finaly return
        return !empty($value)?$value:false;



    }
```

**What is the problem please help me.**
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please print the $sql?

Comment: this is the link for all the files. Please help https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nKInfhAngSR3Q0OHBibW1sUzg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please paste the sql only.It will be easy to debug

Comment: do you mean the sql query. all the files queries are in the files in the shareable link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nKInfhAngSR3Q0OHBibW1sUzg/view?usp=sharing